# Files missing from custom module npm package

Tags: javascript, npm, package

I created a new npm package (leon-theme) here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/leon-theme

Github here: https://github.com/leongaban/leon-theme

Locally after running `npm run build` in the custom package, the dist folder builds correct, however when I publish it, all the files are missing except for the README and package.json.

Thus if I try to import my new package into a brand new react app, it cannot find the module.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/leon-theme?activeTab=code

### tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES6",
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "outDir": "./dist/lib/es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

#### main package.json

```
{
  "name": "leon-theme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "module": "lib/es6/index.js",
  "description": "A simple React style & component library",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist/lib && tsc --build"
  },
  "author": "Leon Gaban",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.22",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index/.d.ts"
}
```

#### package.json in dist folder

```
{
  "name": "leon-theme",
  "version": "0.0.6",
  "module": "lib/es6/index.js",
  "description": "A simple React style & component library",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/leongaban/leon-theme",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/leongaban/leon-theme/issues"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/leongaban/leon-theme.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "javascript",
    "theme",
    "buttons",
    "leon"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist/lib && tsc --build"
  },
  "author": "Leon Gaban",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.22",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index/.d.ts"
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, the problem is the publishing to npm? Since the github shows the files.

Comment: @Geshode yes problem is with npmjs.org

Comment: Why is the version in your dist package.json 0.0.6, but in your root 1.0.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dist/package.json file is causing this problem, it looks like a trimmed down version of the package.json, same thing with the README.md. You don't need those files in the dist folder, they'll get included regardless. Read more [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#files).

Delete those two files and it works correctly.

The problem is also nothing to do with npmjs.org specifically but with npm. You can test these changes by just running `npm pack` which will make a TAR file (leon-theme-1.0.0.tgz) of the package that would be published. You can open this file with something like 7-zip, or the command output shows the included files.

With the dist/package.json and dist/README.md removed the output now shows the files included:

```
PS \repos\leon-theme> npm pack
npm notice 
npm notice package: leon-theme@1.0.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===
npm notice 226B dist/lib/es6/components/Button/Button.js
npm notice 69B  dist/lib/es6/components/Button/index.js
npm notice 131B dist/lib/es6/components/index.js
npm notice 72B  dist/lib/es6/components/LeonTheme/index.js
npm notice 63B  dist/lib/es6/index.js
npm notice 305B dist/lib/es6/components/LeonTheme/LeonTheme.js
npm notice 518B package.json
npm notice 327B dist/lib/es6/components/Button/Button.js.map
npm notice 171B dist/lib/es6/components/Button/index.js.map
npm notice 222B dist/lib/es6/components/index.js.map
npm notice 174B dist/lib/es6/components/LeonTheme/index.js.map
npm notice 127B dist/lib/es6/index.js.map
npm notice 387B dist/lib/es6/components/LeonTheme/LeonTheme.js.map
npm notice 184B README.md
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
npm notice name:          leon-theme
npm notice version:       1.0.0
npm notice filename:      leon-theme-1.0.0.tgz
npm notice package size:  1.4 kB
npm notice unpacked size: 3.0 kB
npm notice shasum:        8e22b9a71680a31c72bbc813815dc30249b49f1b
npm notice integrity:     sha512-Nj92cJ+JOybD/[...]Hse0hWLqWWuFA==
npm notice total files:   14
npm notice
leon-theme-1.0.0.tgz
```

Comment: Thanks! I see dist folder files now :)